# I want to perform some action when a mouse is over JMenuItem. What listener should I use?

Tags: java, swing, listeners

I want to perform some action when a mouse is over JMenuItem. What listener should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [MouseListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html). Its method mouseEntered() and mouseExited() will be helpful to you.

Comment: And what if i want to activate listener when navigating in menu with keyboard and not mouse? :S

Answer (score 2):

If 'some action' happens to be 'show a message', look at [JComponent.setToolTipText(String)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setToolTipText%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: .. yoooouuu suggesting a FocusListener? As we all know, it's usefulness is limited to very rare contexts :-)

Comment: @kleopatra:  Yes, and apparently not menu items at all.  A quick test suggests they do not fire on hover by mouse, or keyboard 'focus' as I would have thought of it.  Butchering answer to suit.  :P

Answer (score 2):

and alternative is

```
    menuItem1.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            ButtonModel model = (ButtonModel) e.getSource();
            if (model.isRollover()) {
                // some stuff
            }// may be another states from ButtonModel
        }
    });
```

Comment: sounds cool - just curious did you try it? Generally, it's a good-thing to go for a higher level state, if availabel. The only problem I see in practice, is that it's hard to get exactly a change in _rollover_ because changeEvent is a compound notification (or too fine-grained, depending on perspective)

Comment: And what if i want to activate listener when navigating in menu with keyboard and not mouse?

Comment: @Nika - yeah indeed, what did you find out when you tried it?

Comment: closing the circle: third iteration - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973875/why-my-changelistener-reacts-only-for-jmenu-and-not-for-jmenuitem