# How to change icon for JmenuItem on rollover

Tags: java, swing, rollover, jmenu, jmenuitem

I want to put a rollover effect in my JMenu this is my code:

```
Icon firstPicAcc= new ImageIcon(Welcome.class.getResource("/app/resources/user1.jpg"));
    Icon secPicAcc= new  ImageIcon(Welcome.class.getResource("/app/resources/user2.jpg"));
    JMenu mnAccountSettings = new JMenu("Account Settings");
    mnAccountSettings.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent arg0) {
        }
    });

    mnAccountSettings.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    mnAccountSettings.setForeground(new Color(0, 153, 0));
    mnAccountSettings.setBackground(new Color(255, 204, 255));
    mnAccountSettings.setRolloverEnabled(true);
    mnAccountSettings.setIcon(firstPicAcc);
    mnAccountSettings.setRolloverIcon(secPicAcc);

    mnAccount.add(mnAccountSettings);
```

how can i do that? thanks!
What should happen is when I  rolled my mouse over the JMenu bar the original icon should change into another icon.

Comment: What exactly is supposed to happen? And can you post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What should happen is when I  rolled my mouse over the JMenu bar the original icon should change into another icon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to do is add a [**ChangeListener**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/changelistener.html) to the `JMenuItem` and check if it's `selected` or `armed` and change the `icon` accordingly. The `ChangeListener` works for both keyboard and mouse.

See [this good read by @kleopatra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5976336/2587435)

```
private JMenuItem createMenuItem(final ImageIcon icon, String title) {
    JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(title);
    item.setIcon(icon);

    ChangeListener cl = new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() instanceof JMenuItem) {
                JMenuItem item = (JMenuItem) e.getSource();
                if (item.isSelected() || item.isArmed()) {
                    item.setIcon(stackIcon);
                } else {
                    item.setIcon(icon);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    item.addChangeListener(cl);

    return item;
}
```

[image]

Here is running example. Just replace images with yours

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class RolloverMenuItem {
    ImageIcon stackIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/stackoverflow2.png"));

    public RolloverMenuItem() {
        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/image/new.gif"));
        ImageIcon saveIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/image/open.gif"));
        ImageIcon openIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/image/save.gif"));

        JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
        menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        JMenuItem item1 = createMenuItem(newIcon, "New");
        JMenuItem item2 = createMenuItem(openIcon, "Open");
        JMenuItem item3 = createMenuItem(saveIcon, "Save");
        menu.add(item1);
        menu.add(item2);
        menu.add(item3);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.add(menu);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rollover MenuItem");
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 250);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JMenuItem createMenuItem(final ImageIcon icon, String title) {
        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(title);
        item.setIcon(icon);

        ChangeListener cl = new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() instanceof JMenuItem) {
                    JMenuItem item = (JMenuItem) e.getSource();
                    if (item.isSelected() || item.isArmed()) {
                        item.setIcon(stackIcon);
                    } else {
                        item.setIcon(icon);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        item.addChangeListener(cl);

        return item;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new RolloverMenuItem();
            }
        });
    }
}
```